# FirebaseListAdapter not able to get data from firebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

This is method to load data from firebase to listView.

Tried `FirebaseListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference()......)`
before this but it was showing error.

then added FirebaseListOptions with the query as shown..
but this code fails to load data in the listView.

[image]

```
    private void displayChatMessage() {

        ListView listOfMessage = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatMessage");

        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options){
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {

                //Get references to the views of list_item.xml
                TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
                messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));

            }
        };
        listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

}

Snippet to push data in Firebase..

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatMessage").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
```

Comment: where is it giving the error and what type of error?

Comment: Add your error message also.

Comment: There is no syntax error it is logical error it seems . Data from firebase Database is not getting loaded in the  **ListView** .

Comment: is .getReference("ChatMessage") in the query line correct ?

Comment: and no idea why ListViewAdapter<Chatmessage>(this,R.layout.list_item,...,....) was showing syntax error.

Comment: Runtime Exception Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Layout cannot be null. Call setLayout.
                      at com.firebase.ui.common.Preconditions.assertNonNull(Preconditions.java:24)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions$Builder.build(FirebaseListOptions.java:162)
                      at com.example.rishabh.chatingapp.MainActivity.displayChatMessage(MainActivity.java:135)
                      at com.example.rishabh.chatingapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:82)

Comment: Please add the code where you instantiate the `listOfMessage`.